# Strange Branch Showing Up In Git

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm not sure how this happened, but recently I noticed a strange remote branch that shows up when i run the command `git branch -a`

```
remotes/origin/pr/121
remotes/origin/pr/122
remotes/origin/pr/126
```

how can I remove these remote branches?

I tried `git push origin --delete pr/121` and various forms of that but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your repository is hosted on GitHub.
They will create such a branch for each pull request.

Have a look at https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally

Comment: That makes sense. If I close the pull request, will that automatically delete the remote branch?

Comment: In addition, I think this is the correct answer, and I'm hoping that closing the pull request will delete the remote.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a branch I usually use this format

```
git push origin :pr/121
```

Mind the `:`

Think of it as a special condition of the

```
git push remote [local-branch]:[remote-branch]
```

but for local you choose nothing, so it's like push blank to remote-branch, and it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote branch -dr pr/121` should work for deleting the tracking branches.

> -r
>   --remotes
>
> ```
> List or delete (if used with -d) the remote-tracking branches.
> ```

Quote from git manual.

However, for actually deleting the branch on the remote too: Assuming you have push access `git push origin :121` should push nothing over the branch 121 at origin ultimately removing it.